# For a dict of list values, find the key with the maximum value for each index in the list

Tags: python

I have a dict with a few names as the keys, and each name has a value of a list with some numbers. I want to get the name (key) with the maximum value for each index of the list value.

I tried to write the following code but it doesn't work, I obtain the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'` and I don't know why.

This is the code:

```
from Scheduler import Scheduler

class MaxSNR(Scheduler):
    def allocuteUR(self, mapMobileMkn, tailleFrequence=1):
        mapUniteResource = ["NonAllouer" for x in range(tailleFrequence)]
        mknMax = max(mapMobileMkn, key=mapMobileMkn.get)
        return mknMax

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MaxSNR()
    
    mapUniteResource = m.allocuteUR({'patrick': [40, 5], 'michel': [8, 3], 'edgard': [1, 10]}, tailleFrequence=2)
    for key in mapUniteResource.keys:
        nombre = MaxSNR(mapUniteResource)
        print(nombre)
```

For the example above I expect the output to be:

```
patrick
edgard
```

Because 40 is the maximum value of the first index and 10 is the maximum value of the second index.

Comment: `allocuteUR` returns the ***key*** with the maximum value. You seem to treat it as a dict...

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand what I have to do to make my scrib work

Comment: It's hard to say as you didn't explain what the code is supposed to do... Try to explain the goal and provide a [mre]. You are currently passing a dict to your function and it returns a key (which is a string) which you save to `mapUniteResource`. Then you treat it like a dict by trying to access its keys. I'm not sure why you override the variable with a new value. Maybe you meant it to be a list?

Comment: For me, in mapUniteResouce, the goal is to compare all the first value and print the name who as the biggest, then doing the same thing with the second value... At the end, I want tohave a lot of value for each name, and I want to compare each first one, each first two, ... and have each time the name of people who has the biggest for each comparison

Comment: I think I understand. So for example for: `{patrick : [40,5] , michel : [8,3] , edgard: [1,10]}` you want the output to be: `patrick, edgard` because 40 is the biggest of the first values and 10 is the biggest of the second values?

Answer (score 0):

- It will be more convenient to first separate the dict to `names` and `values`.
- Now we want to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the values in order to iterate over the index-matching items.
- Now we need to find the index of the maximum value, so we can take its matching name.

```py
d = {'patrick': [40, 5], 'michel': [8, 3], 'edgard': [1, 10]}
names, values = zip(*d.items())
for column in zip(*values):
    index = max(range(len(column)), key=lambda i: column[i])
    print(index, names[index])
```

Will give:

```
0 patrick
2 edgard
```